# Do NSShowAllViews and NSShowAllDrawing work with Xcode 3, OS X 10.5.6?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, macos

I am trying to enable these debugging preferences (NSShowAllViews, NSShowAllDrawing) as shown here:
http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECAPPKITVIEWS

Using this method:
http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#FIGXCODEENV

Are these features present in Xcode 3 and OS X 10.5.6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment variable list in the executable editor is present in Xcode 3, yes.

The reason it's not working is those are not environment variables. They are preferences, and you have to set them as such.

You can do that from Xcode's executable editor by adding a few arguments:

- `-NSShowAllViews`
- `YES`
- `-NSShowAllDrawing`
- `YES`

This will set those preferences in `NSArgumentDomain`, which is non-persistent.

Comment: I'm trying to add this in Arguments section of the executable, and nothing is happening.  Any suggestions ?

Comment: As of Snow Leopard, `NSShowAllViews` works just fine, but `NSShowAllDrawing` doesn't. You should file a bug report: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: NSShowAllDrawing has always been a bit finicky. If you're looking to debug view issues and ShowAllViews isn't enough, you should check out http://sparkinspector.com/ (only for iOS apps at the moment)